# Apex Flex Queue jobs monitoring

Tags: scheduled-apex, apex-flex-queue

I've enabled critical update for apex flex queue in my developer org. Also scheduled more than 20 jobs.

Now, I wanted to monitor the jobs but when I go to Monitor -> Jobs there is no option as **Apex Flex Queue** as mentioned in the release notes [here](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_apex_flex_queue_ga.htm)

I queried on scheduled jobs and found that all the jobs are scheduled but the screen to see the scheduled jobs is not visible. What am I missing here? Is it not available in developer org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't see the Apex Flex Queue option after enabling the critical update, you need to contact Salesforce support to enable it on the backend. They had to do this for our sandboxes and production environments. After doing this, you will be able to find it by going to Setup > Monitoring > Apex Flex Queue

Answer (score 1):

We have it activated in our sandboxes, production, and developer edition orgs, and nowhere is there an option for Jobs | Apex Flex Queue. You can see the scheduled jobs in Setup > Monitoring > Apex Jobs. There's a new status called "Holding" that you can filter on. However, without the Flex Queue screen being available, you can't change the order in which they will execute (as far as I'm aware). I also signed up for a pre-release Developer Edition and Enterprise Edition, and the ability to adjust the flex queue was not found there, either.

Answer (score 0):

The flex queue has to be enabled before you can see the jobs. See https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/FlexQueue. It's discussed in the above article. The feature is enabled via a critical update that's also caused an issue for many users where I've included the details below.

There appears to be a known issue that's in review: [Spring 15 -max number of APEX Scheduled jobs(5) for Trial orgs](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Y2RAAU). While this issue is listed as for Trial orgs, posts on Success.Salesforce.com would indicated that many DE users are also having the same issue.

> Summary
>   Max number of Apex scheduled jobs is limited to 5 in trial Orgs. Previously, it was 100.
>
> Repro
>   Create 5 Scheduled jobs in a trial ORG 
>   Try to create another Scheduled job on top of the existing jobs. 
>   An error will be received as follows:
>
> ERROR: 
>   You have exceeded the max number of APEX Scheduled jobs(5)

Comment: A trial org is a specific type of org, of which a Developer Edition is not. The limits for developer editions are separate, and documented.

Comment: Yes, I know. I also saw numerous posts when I ran a search that reported the same issue with Dev Orgs. Initial docs on limits for SP15 stated it would be 5 for a DE, but the current docs show 100. Apparently the same bug must affect both.

Comment: But still, regardless of that issue, there should still be a Flex Queue menu option if the flex queue is enabled, and the user made no statement about getting an error when there were just five items queued. We're using the critical update today in production and see it working just fine, except we can't re-order the tasks, as even our production org, which has been around for years, also doesn't have that menu option.

Comment: The flex queue has to be enabled before you can see the jobs. https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/FlexQueue. There's a critical update that has caused the issue that users are having. Its mentioned in this article.

Comment: I guess raising ticket with support would be the correct idea. As we can't assume that the bug for trial org is applicable to other orgs as well.